# Calculate conditional probability w.r.t. singular event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables and the event $\{Y=y\}$ has measure zero.

Furthermore, there is a joint density function $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$.

Now, I was wondering: 
When is the conditional probability $P(X \in A; {Y=y})$ well-defined and if it is, how  or when could I compute it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have joint density, it's pretty straightforward: $$P(X\in A|Y=y)=\frac {\int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx}{\int_{R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx}$$